# Проблемы с версткой в шаблоне при определенных условиях

Tags: php, вёрстка

Есть вот такой кусок PHP кода (кусок файла шаблона movement.tpl):

```
/* on attack, raid */
$aantal = count($database->getMovement(3,$village->wid,0));
echo "$aantal";
echo "<br>";
var_dump($aantal);
$aantal1 = count($database->getMovement(3,$village->wid,0));
$aantal2 = $database->getMovement(3,$village->wid,0);
for($i=0;$i<$aantal1;$i++){
    if($aantal2[$i]['attack_type'] == 2) { $aantal -= 1; }
}
if($aantal > 0){
    if(!empty($NextArrival2)) { reset($NextArrival2); }
        foreach($aantal2 as $receive) {
            if ($receive['attack_type'] != 2) {
                $action = 'att2';
                $aclass = 'a2';
                $title = ''.OWN_ATTACKING_TROOPS.'';
                $short = ''.ATTACK.'';
                $NextArrival2[] = $receive['endtime'];
            }
        }
    echo '<tr><td class="typ"><a href="build.php?id=39"><img src="img/x.gif" class="'.$action.'" alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" /></a><span class="'.$aclass.'">&raquo;</span></td>
    <td><div class="mov"><span class="'.$aclass.'">'.$aantal.'&nbsp;'.$short.'</span></div><div class="dur_r">in&nbsp;<span id="timer'.$timer.'">'.$generator->getTimeFormat(min($NextArrival2)-time()).'</span>&nbsp;'.HOURS.'</div></div></td></tr>';
    $timer += 1;
}
```

Если отправляю одну атаку, то ломается верстка и выглядит вот так:
[image: Поломанная верстка]

Если атак более одной, то все ОК и выглядит вот так:
[image: Все хорошо]

По-моему за все отвечает переменная $aantal. Но когда переменная $aantal равна 1 не срабатывает вот этот блок:

```
echo '<tr><td class="typ"><a href="build.php?id=39"><img src="img/x.gif" class="'.$action.'" alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" /></a><span class="'.$aclass.'">&raquo;</span></td>
    <td><div class="mov"><span class="'.$aclass.'">'.$aantal.'&nbsp;'.$short.'</span></div><div class="dur_r">in&nbsp;<span id="timer'.$timer.'">'.$generator->getTimeFormat(min($NextArrival2)-time()).'</span>&nbsp;'.HOURS.'</div></div></td></tr>';
    $timer += 1;
```

Почему так происходит? Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: возможно глупый вопрос, но вы уверены в том, что в переменной именно единица? Попробуйте через вардамп вывести ее значение

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, проблема в $aantal -= 1;

```
for($i=0;$i<$aantal1;$i++){
    if($aantal2[$i]['attack_type'] == 2) { $aantal -= 1; }
}
```

ну и до кучи:

```
$aantal1 = count($database->getMovement(3,$village->wid,0));
$aantal2 = $database->getMovement(3,$village->wid,0);
```

Это двойной (на самом деле там еще есть) запрос одного и того же у базы, чтоб наверняка?

```
$title = ''.OWN_ATTACKING_TROOPS.'';
$short = ''.ATTACK.'';
```

Зачем там пустые строки? Зачем хранить локализацию в константах?

upd

> кусок файла **шаблона** movement.tpl

```
$database->...
```

><

```
echo "$aantal";
```

если в кавычки не взять, то не эхнется?